# Create a new column based on different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5  Col6  Col7  
1     A    T     1    AG   NBL   NH
2     A    T     1    NAG  BL    NH
3     A    M     2    NAG  NBL   HL 
4     NS   M     1    NAG  BL    NH
5     NS   T     1    NAG  NBL   HL 
6     A    M     2    NAG  NBL   HL
```

I want to create a new column based on this conditions:

```
IF Col5 = 'AG' AND Col2 = 'A' AND Col3 = 'M' AND Col4 = 1 Then *(In the NewColumn)*  'A1'

IF Col5 = 'AG' AND Col2 = 'A' AND Col3 = 'M' AND Col4 = 0 Then *(In the NewColumn)*  'A2'

IF Col6 = 'BL' AND Col2 = 'A' AND Col3 = 'M' AND Col4 = 1 Then *(In the NewColumn)*  'B1'

IF Col6 = 'BL' AND Col2 = 'A' AND Col3 = 'M' AND Col4 = 0 Then *(In the NewColumn)*  'B2'

IF Col7 = 'HL' AND Col2 = 'A' AND Col3 = 'M' AND Col4 = 1 Then *(In the NewColumn)*  'H1'

IF Col6 = 'HL' AND Col2 = 'A' AND Col3 = 'M' AND Col4 = 0 Then *(In the NewColumn)*  'H2'
```

I have many different conditions in the original df but I'm trying to create a way just to add this conditions.
I'm working with phyton in jupyter

Comment: Have you tried to do a df.apply() based on your conditions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the logic here is pretty complicated, I would suggest putting your conditions inside a function, and using [DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to call that function for every row in your dataset. Here's how I would translate your example into Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")


def classify(row):
    Col2 = row["Col2"]
    Col3 = row["Col3"]
    Col4 = row["Col4"]
    Col5 = row["Col5"]
    Col6 = row["Col6"]
    Col7 = row["Col7"]
    if Col5 == 'AG' and Col2 == 'A' and Col3 == 'M' and Col4 == 1:
        return 'A1'

    if Col5 == 'AG' and Col2 == 'A' and Col3 == 'M' and Col4 == 0:
        return 'A2'

    if Col6 == 'BL' and Col2 == 'A' and Col3 == 'M' and Col4 == 1:
        return 'B1'

    if Col6 == 'BL' and Col2 == 'A' and Col3 == 'M' and Col4 == 0:
        return 'B2'

    if Col7 == 'HL' and Col2 == 'A' and Col3 == 'M' and Col4 == 1:
        return 'H1'

    if Col6 == 'HL' and Col2 == 'A' and Col3 == 'M' and Col4 == 0:
        return 'H2'

    # No match
    return None


df["NewCol"] = df.apply(classify, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Note: I tried this function on your dataset, and I get the following result, which is probably not what you want:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3  Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 NewCol
0     1    A    T     1   AG  NBL   NH   None
1     2    A    T     1  NAG   BL   NH   None
2     3    A    M     2  NAG  NBL   HL   None
3     4   NS    M     1  NAG   BL   NH   None
4     5   NS    T     1  NAG  NBL   HL   None
5     6    A    M     2  NAG  NBL   HL   None
```

Inspecting the individual rows, they seem to be correct - none of them follow any of your rules. I'd suggest double checking that your rules are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I find [numpy.select()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to be a good fit for this problem where you have lots of conditions and need to map it a value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def my_transform(row: pd.Series):
    choices = [all([row['Col5'].strip() == 'AG', row['Col4'] == 1]), 
               all([row['Col5'].strip() == 'AG', row['Col4'] == 0]), True]
    results = ['A1', 'A2', 'Default']
    return np.select(choices, results)

df['my_new_col'] = df.apply(my_transform, axis=1)
```

What select does is it checks for the index of the first truthy value and returns the value corresponding to that index from the second parameter passed to it (here `results`). Here I have simplified your first two rules but you could expand on them to fit your exact situation.